# Tangent sheaf of a rational curve is a subsheaf of tangent sheaf of ambient space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth, proper variety, and $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to X$ be a finite morphism. Then it is claimed that $f^* T_X$ contains $T_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ as a subsheaf. However, I did not see the reason.

I think we have exact sequence
$$f^* \Omega_{X} \to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1/X} \to 0.$$

Taking the dual sheaf, we have

$$0 \to (\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1/X})^\vee \to T_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to f^*T_{X}.$$

Then the problem because why $(\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1/X})^\vee=0$?

Comment: This is false if $f$ is inseparable. But you probably missed some hypothesis in the statement.